# Таймер на питоне telebot

Tags: python, telebot

Пользователь вводит две даты ДД.ММ.ГГГГ (пример: 23.11.2024 и 23.11.2025), нужно рассчитать соотношение между ними как на скрине, чтобы выводилось сколько прошло дней (процентов) "месяцев, дней, часов, минут, секунд" - желательно чтобы эти пункты появлялись после старта времени(скрин приложен). Как это лучше сделать и нужно ли это проводить через базу данных?

[image: пример][image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: а вы уже попробовали что-то сделать?